# What is the name of the relationship between someone and his/her relative?

Tags: vocabulary

If the relationship between someone and their friend is "Friendship", then
what is the name of the relationship between someone and his/her relative?

Context:
e.g. I cherish my friendship with John.

e.g. I cherish my …………… with Oliver -He is my cousin-

Comment: It is not clear whether you asking for **(1)** a word that simply expresses the fact that somebody **is** your relative, and nothing more, or **(2)** a word that refers to your **interaction** with somebody as a relative. Note that (1) can exist without (2): one can have relatives that one never interacts with (in that respect being a relative is not analogous to being a friend).

Comment: My intended question is, if you call the relationship between you and your friend "friendship", so what do you call the relationship between you and your relative?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about a cousin, because some of your comments suggest that, or about a relationship with any relative? Merriam-Webster has cousinage, but it's rare in my opinion https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cousinage

Comment: @StuartF  Yes, with any relative

Is "kinship" the right word?

Answer (score 2):

A friendship is a relationship between people that may change over time as the friends come to know each other better.

A relationship with kin is a kinship, but it’s static, not dynamic. Kinship is a defined relationship like brother or cousin, and stays the same no matter how well you are acquainted.  Different cultures define kinship relationships differently, especially, perhaps, what we call in-laws in English—relatives because of marriage rather than blood lines.

Comment: Okay @Xanne, my precise question is what is the name of the relationship between someone and their cousin?

Comment: No idea. That wasn’t your posted question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a family relationship, none are closer. So it would be appropriate to refer to it as your *relationship* with your cousin.

Comment: Is "kinship" the right word?

Answer (score 1):

Use **kinship**, because you are referring to a

> relationship:  the way in which two or more people feel and behave towards each other
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/relationship)

in particular, you refer to a family relationship. This is known as

> **kinship** = the relationship between members of the same family
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/kinship)

The word comes from *kin*, which is:

> a group of persons of common ancestry
>
> [Merriam Wenster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kin)

And the suffix *-ship*

> = -ship
> state : condition : quality. Example:friendship
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ship)

Comment: What do we call a relationship between someone and their cousin?
And what do we call a one between someone and their brother? 

I think family relationship is so general!